# dataframe change size and the convert to panel python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, panel, reshape

I have a question on how to change dataframe to a panel while changinig the dimensions of the dataframe.
Originally I have a data frame with 2000 rows and 784 colmuns:

```
data=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(2000,784))
data.shape
(2000, 784)
```

I would like to turn each column into a 28*28 dataframe and then store this into a panel like structure with the size (2000,28,28) or 2000 28 by 28 dataframes.
Looking at some [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17243186/assigning-dataframe-to-panel-in-pandas), I tried:

```
data_panel=pd.Panel(dict([ (i,data) for i in range(2000)]))
data_panel
<class 'pandas.core.panel.Panel'>
Dimensions: 2000 (items) x 2000 (major_axis) x 784 (minor_axis)
Items axis: 0 to 1999
Major_axis axis: 0 to 1999
Minor_axis axis: 0 to 783
```

But that is not what I want. The items axis is correct, but I would like the major axis and minor axis to be 28 by 28.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What seems to be the problem? This works:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(2000,784))

panel = pd.Panel(data.values.reshape(2000, 28, 28))

# In [49]: q.panel[42].shape
# Out[49]: (28, 28)

# In [51]: q.panel
# Out[51]:
# <class 'pandas.core.panel.Panel'>
# Dimensions: 2000 (items) x 28 (major_axis) x 28 (minor_axis)
# Items axis: 0 to 1999
# Major_axis axis: 0 to 27
# Minor_axis axis: 0 to 27
```